# How to invoke `\phi` only from `newtxmath` package?

Tags: greek, letters

A minimal working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\Huge

$$\phi$$

\end{document}
```

**Question:** ***How to invoke `\phi` only from `newtxmath` package?*** Note that I don't like to invoke any other letters from `newtxmath`. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There you go.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{ntxletters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{ntxletters}{30}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\Huge

\[\phi, \bm{\phi}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: phi]

---

Thanks to @marmot pointing out [this previous answer by @AlanMunn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388/164314). As @AlanMunn said in that answer, one needs some basic knowledge about font declarations before performing the trick. This key line of code in [`newtxmath.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/tex/newtxmath.sty):

```
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{letters}{30}
```

tells us that we should be looking for lines that declare `letters`. Indeed, we find

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Math Italic %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
... ... ...
    \DeclareSymbolFont{letters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
    \SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}
... ... ...
```

Thus, the suggested solution.

Comment: It's important to find `ntxmi`! Although I know the method, but I didn't find `ntxmi`!

Comment: Very kind Ruixi...marmot not exist..but there's his substitute :-) Maybe you should edit the answer since there are no comments referring to the two users.