# Export Greek font (italic, upright, bold) from 'newtxmath' package with libertine option

Tags: fonts, symbols, greek, newtxmath

Is there a way to export just a *single* symbol from the font used by `newtxmath` with `libertine` option? Being be more specific, I would need both the italic and the upright Greek letters (in bold too) without loading the `newtxmath` package. For instance, this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\tau\uptau\boldsymbol{\uptau}$
\end{document}
```

produces that
[image]
How can I export these three characters (respectively italic, upright and bold)?
I tried with something like

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{NEWTXletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{NEWTXletters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\newtxtau}{\mathord}{NEWTXletters}{28}
```

in the preamble, as suggested by [@Ruixi Zhang and @Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453406/how-to-invoke-phi-only-from-newtxmath-package) and others; that is fantastic, but so I only get the Greek italic letters of the default option, which is not libertine! In `newtxmath.sty` there is something like `DeclareMathSymbol{\tauup}{\mathord}{lettersA}{28}`, but I don't know how to export it. Moreover, I tried to export them as .eps files, but that's not the same thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want the letters from Libertine, load that font instead?

Comment: Would a solution based on `unicode-math` or `mathspec` work for you? Can you use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX?

Comment: No. I use pdfLaTeX

Comment: @TFra6 Thank you so much for mentioning me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original (with `newtxmath` and `libertine` option)

```latex
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\begin{document}

$\tau\uptau\boldsymbol{\uptau}$

\end{document}
```

With the imported symbols

```latex
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{nxlmi}{\skewchar\font=127}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
   <-6.3> s*[1] nxlmi035
   <6.3-8.6> s*[1] nxlmi037
   <8.6-> s*[1] nxlmi03
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{nxlmi}{b}{it}{
  <-6.3> s*[1] nxlbmi035
  <6.3-8.6> s*[1] nxlbmi037
  <8.6-> s*[1] nxlbmi03
}{}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ntxmia}{\skewchar\font=127}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}{
   <-> s*[1] nxlmia
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}{
   <-> s*[1] nxlbmia
}{}


\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxlibletters}{OML}{nxlmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{ntxlibletters}{bold}{OML}{nxlmi}{b}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxlibupletters}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{ntxlibupletters}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{ntxlibletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uptau}{\mathord}{ntxlibupletters}{"1C}

\begin{document}

$\tau\uptau\boldsymbol{\uptau}$

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

[image]

Adjust the factor `[1]` in the font shape declarations to match the font you use. It's a magnification factor; using `s*[0.9]` reduces the font size at 90%.